# Why the difference in audio volume via bluetooth?

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth

I hope I'm in the right spot for this.

I have my volume on the phone set to 100%. I connect via bluetooth to my car. My car's radio volume goes from 0 to 45. Now, when I listen to music, my car's volume is set to 10-15. However, when I listen to a book from Audible, or make a phone call, the radio volume needs to get at 37+ to be able to hear it. Is there anything I can do to equalize the volume between apps?

Comment: It's not strictly about Bluetooth. Some cars let you adjust volume specifically for phone calls, but I have that too. When I listen to music, my radio volume is 8-10, when I listen to audiobooks, it's generally 20.

Comment: My car system, an aftermarket Pioneer CarPlay system, let's you balance every input separately, including direct from the phone, 'iPod', navigation voice, phone call, iMessage reading etc. You do it simply by tweaking the volume buttons on the steering wheel as that particular 'noise' is playing. The only one you must do from the unit itself is the overall balance to the built-in radio. I'd have a look at the manual, see what your unit can do.

Comment: @Tetsujin: I can do mine on a per app basis as well. I'm just wondering why the vast difference in volume output between the different apps.

Comment: You're not really comparing like with like - unless your choice of music is classical, the volume difference can be explained by the music industry's fixation with loudness - Google 'the loudness war'.

Answer (score 1):

Every output device has a maximum volume level in its settings. This is different than the current listening volume of the main volume.

For instance,  I have internal speakers, external speakers, alerts, midi Dj'ing equipment and bluetooth PA system speakers.

If I go to the sound preferences, there are different default volumes for each device. No matter the main volume those will override current main volume on plug in , activation or connection of a different device.

Individually they all have their own settings and ultimately they can be found in the sound preferences.

Then as some mentioned, the device you are connecting to, can also have its own defaults that override your connecting device.